# Логическое удаление из БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net, база-данных

Часто встречаю в чужих проектах следующее.

У сущности имеется булево свойство IsDeleting.
И при удалени из БД, объект не удаляется, вместо этого свойство IsDeleting = true.
Ну и соответствено все объекты у которых IsDeleting = true не отображаются в DataGrid'e.

Почему они так делают? Неужели чтоб потом любую сущность можно было легко востановить.

Comment: Microsoft рекомендует делать это немного [по-другому](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872): вы сообщаете `DbContext`'у, что хотите удалить объект, а он фактически удаляет этот и другие удалённые объекты на `SaveChanges()`. Для чего так делают другие проекты, стоить спросить у них (ну или посмотреть, как они пользуются этим свойством).

В любом случае, удалять объект из базы _немедленно_ не имеет смысла: общение с базой данных — дорогая операция, так что лучше накопить множество изменений и синхронизироваться с базой «в один присест».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорей не IsDeleting, а IsDeleted.
Объект просто помечается как удалённый. Он физически остаётся, но этот признак во всей логике приложения заставляет "не видеть" этот объект.
Это делается для того, чтобы сохранить данные. Если объект удалить - то всё, это практически не обратимо. Скажем, если по ошибке ваше приложение удалит всех пользователей - то вы расстроитесь? А если был бы просто этот признак, то все записи бы остались.
Кстати, кроме булевского варианта, встречаются ещё время и такого же как и айдишник - ссылка на лог.

Answer (score 1):

Если логическое удаление планируется делать в целях сохранения данных для отчетности, то есть альтернатива проще [Моментальные снимки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175158.aspx).
Это не совсем одно и то же, но иногда будет лучшим решением чем логического удаления, так как можно не хранить даты удаления, апдейта, вставки во всех таблицах, а сохранить дату актуальности, к примеру, в имени БД.